# PHP Division isn't calculating property, help please

Tags: php, divide

I have one variable ($TotalCountyTaxAmount) I want to divide by 365 to calculate a daily tax rate. In this example the variable value is 1614.21. When I divide the variable by the number of days (e.g. $TCA / $days), I get 0.2261 which is incorrect.  The correct answer should be 4.42. When I change the order (e.g. $days / $TCA) I get a result of 365.

```
//calculate daily tax rate
$days = '365';
$TCA = str_replace("$", "", $TotalCountyTaxAmount); //strip dollar sign 
echo ($days / $TCA);  
echo ($TCA / $days);
```

TIA

I have tried using the number_format() which didn't work. I am limited to the functions available [here](https://support.actionstep.com/support/solutions/articles/150000019802-blacklisted-whitelisted-php-for-calculated-merge-fields)

Comment: Works for me.  `$days = '365'; $TCA = '1614.21'; echo ($TCA / $days);` gives me `4.4224931506849`.  As a side note, not sure why you're using strings for numeric values?  PHP is great for type juggling, by maybe just use `$days = 365;` and avoid any potential issues with type conversion further down the line?)

Comment: It works correctly for me as per output you have mention(0.2261168001685,4.4224931506849).What is issue with this ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the output is correct and you confuse between that two operation [(check this)](https://3v4l.org/ARlAU#v8.1.20).

`0.2261` or more precise `0.2261168001685` is the result of `$days / $TCA`, and the result of `$TCA / $days / $days` is `4.4224931506849`.

also you can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the numeric output.